# Removing a given extension from a file

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a below input file(`input.txt`). I want to remove the given extension(ec.txt) in input.txt

Content of input.txt

```
abcd.html
apple
browser.do
image.gif
net.asp
```

and I have an extension check file (`ec.txt`)

Content of `ec.txt`

```
.html
.gif
.do
```

I want to remove the extensions from `input.txt`, for the extensions available in the `ec.txt` file

Content of `output.txt`

```
abcd
apple
browser
image
net.asp
```

Answer (score 2):

this awk one-liner will do the job:

```
awk -F. -v OFS="." 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}$NF in a{NF--}7' ec.txt input.txt
```

Comment: Hi @Kent, this `awk` is not working. Output is same as input.txt

Comment: @GanzRicanz I tested just now, it gave the expected output... make sure your two files are same as the ones in the question.